# PHP SDK - Get User returning '0' on initial visit even if registered

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-authentication

I am testing using facebook registration on a new [site](http://www.goalscreen.com/fbregister.php) of mine. I am trying to set a redirect up using PHP before the registration page loads; in it I check to see if a UID exists and matches one in my registration database - and if so initiate a session and redirect them.

The relevant code I am using at the top is:

```
 require_once("php/fb/facebook.php");

  $facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
));

 $uid = $facebook->getUser();
mysql_connect(....)
if ($uid != "0") 
{$qry="SELECT * FROM users WHERE fbid='$uid'";
    $result=mysql_query($qry);
 $row=mysql_fetch_array($result); $test=mysql_num_rows($result);

If ($test=='1') $_SESSION['username']=$row['Email']; header('Location:mhome.php');
 }
?>
```

When I first visit the site, it always returns '0' (and I have it echoing next to the registration form to be sure). If I hit refresh, the redirect works.

Any ideas why that is and what is the best way to fix it?